# jQuery working not working outside the php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

My jQuery is not working well if placed on the same file with the html the output will be just one value **password**, and **email** will not be displayed, but if placed on a different file when i click on the **Login** button the values `console.log(datatopost)` will disappear (like refreshing) on the console.

HTML Code

```
 <!-- Login Modal -->
      <form id="loginForm" method="post">
        <div class="modal fade" id="loginModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Login to your Account</h5>
                  <!-- SIGN IN ERROR MESSAGE-->
                <div id="loginerrorMessage"></div>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="loginemail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="loginemail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" autocomplete="on">
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="loginpassword" class="sr-only">Confirm Password</label>
                      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="loginpassword" placeholder="Enter Password" autocomplete="on">
                  </div> 

                    <h6>Login as:</h6>
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">

                      <input type="radio" name="loginRadio" class="form-check-input" id="checkbank" value="bank">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="checkbank">Bank</label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="loginRadio" id="checkcustomer" value="customer">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="checkcustomer">Customer</label>
                    </div>

                   <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="loginRadio" id="checkadmin" value="admin">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="checkadmin">Admin</label>
                   </div>

              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-auto" data-target="#signupModal" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal">Register</button>

                <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-info" name="login">
                <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Login</button> -->

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </form>
```

jquery code

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#loginForm').on('submit', function(e){
                    //Stop the form from submitting itself to the server.
                    e.preventDefault();
                    let datatopost = $(this).serializeArray();
                    console.log(datatopost);

                });
            });
```

Please I'm just a Beginner...

Answer (score 1):

The email doesn't appear because you didn't set `name="email"`

Correct is:

```
 <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="loginemail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" autocomplete="on">
```

Result:

```
[{
  name: "email",
  value: "test@test.it"
}, {
  name: "password",
  value: "passwordtest"
}, {
  name: "loginRadio",
  value: "bank"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, right click in the console to reveal a menu with "Preserve Log upon Navigation" as an option. Selecting this will keep your console content.

Try it out and run your code again.